# Migration Spring Roo web mvc to gvNIX datatables: how to filter records?

Tags: java, spring-roo, gvnix

One use case is to show the logged in user only his/her own payments and not all payments.

In the “old web mvc scaffold” list view I pushed in the list method and changed it in order to retrieve all payments records of the current logged in user, see code below.

Now I want to migrate to gvNIX datatables. Default it shows all the records in the database.

**Question:** how can I filter only the records of this user?
A simple example would be great or more documentation.

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
public String list(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, @RequestParam(value = "sortFieldName", required = false) String sortFieldName, @RequestParam(value = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder, Model uiModel) {
    System.out.println("In payment list controller");
    if (page != null || size != null) {
        int sizeNo = size == null ? 10 : size.intValue();
        final int firstResult = page == null ? 0 : (page.intValue() - 1) * sizeNo;
        //  uiModel.addAttribute("payments", Payment.findPaymentEntries(firstResult, sizeNo, sortFieldName, sortOrder));
        User currentUser = getCurrentUser();
        List<Payment> paymentList = Payment.findPaymentsByPayUser(getCurrentUser(), firstResult, sizeNo, "transactionDate", "DESC");
        uiModel.addAttribute("payments", paymentList);
        float nrOfPages = (float) Payment.countFindPaymentsByPayUser(currentUser) / sizeNo;
        uiModel.addAttribute("maxPages", (int) ((nrOfPages > (int) nrOfPages || nrOfPages == 0.0) ? nrOfPages + 1 : nrOfPages));
    } else {
        //  uiModel.addAttribute("payments", Payment.findAllPayments(sortFieldName, sortOrder));
        uiModel.addAttribute("payments", Payment.findPaymentsByPayUser(getCurrentUser(), "transactionDate", "DESC").getResultList());
    }
    addDateTimeFormatPatterns(uiModel);
    return "payments/list";
}

    private User getCurrentUser() {
    //  Retrieve the current logged in user and his authentication
    String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    //  Retrieve the user object of the current user
    User user = User.findUsersByEmailAddress(username).getSingleResult();
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Datatables uses Ajax request to retrieve data, the `list` method is used just as page drawer (this is done by `declare precedence` AspectJ directive on `_Roo_GvNIXDatatables.aj`).

To customize the data get by Datatables you should push-in the `setDatatablesBaseFilter`. You can found it in the `_Roo_GvNIXDatatables.aj` file. You can try something like this in your controller:

```
public void setDatatablesBaseFilter(Map<String, Object> propertyMap) {
    // Add here your baseFilters to propertyMap.
    propertyMap.put("paymentUser", getCurrentUser());
}
```

If you need a more complex filter you should customize the `findAllXXX` and `retrieveData` methods (the first for data visualization and the second for the export feature).

Good luck!

Comment: Hi jmvivo, works great! THANKS!

Is there any documentation where this is explained?

Comment: By now, the documentation (in English) is only on https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples. Sorry. In Spanish you can found it in the project page.